# Java - xml GetChildNodes IF and null value

Tags: java

I have got two problems with using xml.

First Problem:

This code working correct. If argument have only one child but not list of childs.

```
doc.getDocumentElement().getChildNodes().item(t).getLastChild().getNodeValue()
```

I would like to prepare something like this:

```
If(doc.getDocumentElement().getChildNodes().item(t).getLastChild().getNodeValue() !=null)
```

but this doesn't work because value is never empty but I need similar If which can check is list of value or not.

Normal Node:

```
<name>Adam</name>
```

List Node:

```
<car>
<tire>yes</tire>
<trunk>yes</trunk>
</car>
```

Second Problem:

If I make nested ChildNodes I`m not able to take value do you know where is a problem?

Example of node:

```
<name>Adam</name>
```

If I wrire this I get "name"

```
doc.getDocumentElement().getChildNodes().item(t).getChildNodes().item(m).getNodeName()
```

If I will write this I will get null but I need "Adam"

```
doc.getDocumentElement().getChildNodes().item(t).getChildNodes().item(m).getNodeName()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

answer - I should use ToLenght() > 1